# ActiveMQ in JBoss - Using JNDI for jdbcPersistentAdaptetr

Tags: oracle, jboss, activemq-classic, jndi

Running ActiveMQ in clustered environment with a Master/Slave relationship using Oracle as a datastore.  Using a jdbcPersistentAdapter.

```
 <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#dataSource" createTablesOnStartup="false" lockKeepAlivePeriod="30000"/>
```

The activemq broker is running embedded in JBoss.

I would like to replace the dataSource bean (contains credentials and url string) with a JNDI reference since that already manages the database connection.  Is this possible?

Comment: There is some info here: http://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration.html
Not sure how up to date it is with latest versions of JBoss and AMQ

Comment: Unfortunately that is for configuring JNDI for the queue and queu factory.  I need to configure JNDI for the persistence within ActiveMQ itself.

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the dataSourcebean from JNDI instead. Something like this should work (using a correct JNDI name from your setup).

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatabase"/>
</bean>
```